# How can I figure out which parameters map to which variables?

Tags: python, debugging, interpreter

My life would be much easier if I could inspect what variables are assigned to what arguments.

*In the line:*

```
self.manager.addState("", [0,0])   # start with 2 empty buckets
```

The `addState` method is defined in `manager` class as taking 2 parameters. It is called in the `playGame` method. I am having trouble understanding what parameters in the signature map to what arguments in the call.

```
def addState (self, parentState, newState) :
        "add state if it's new. Remember its parent"
        if self.seen.has_key(str(newState)) : return
        self.seen[str(newState)] = str(parentState)
        self.queue.append (newState)
```

In the code below, if I assume that `newState` corresponds to `[0,0]` because it is not a singular value(I'm not sure what `""` maps to) then this code should not run at all.

```
self.manager.addState("", [0,0])   # start with 2 empty buckets
```

*Question(s):*

Is my understanding of this correct?

What is the easiest way to inspect the running state of this so I can verify which parameters map to which arguments?

*problem link:*
http://www.openbookproject.net/py4fun/buckets/buckets.py

Comment: Don't forget that lists are also just objects, so "it is not a singular value" may be a misconception. [0,0] definitely is a single object, more specifically a list with two items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if i assume that [0,0] corresponds to parentState and newState then how "" is passed as parameter in

This assumption is your problem.

`[0,0]` is the value of `newState` and `""` is the value of `parentState`

In the example you linked the state of the world is represented by a one dimensional array. The beginning state of the world is two buckets represented by `[0,0]` and it there is a `null` state represented by `""` that only applies at the start of the game.

A very easy way to inspect the state of things is to use `pdb`

```
def addState (self, parentState, newState) :
    "add state if it's new. Remember its parent"

    # Let's augment this by adding a breakpoint
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()    

    if self.seen.has_key(str(newState)) : return
    self.seen[str(newState)] = str(parentState)
    self.queue.append (newState)
    #print '--- Adding ', newState
```

Now when you run this code from the python interpreter `pdb` will break on these lines and you can inspect what's going on.

```
(Pdb) parentState
""
(Pdb) newState
[0,0]
```